# How to create a new database using python and sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(r"D:\aaa.db")
```

Is there a way to automatically create the db file if it doesn't already exist when I connect to it?

Comment: Are you asking how SQLite3 works when it creates a new, empty database?

Comment: so you want to check if the db is there if not create it?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The code you give *does* create `'D:\\aaa.db'` if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 9):

If it isn't created automatically, make sure that you have the directory permissions correct

Answer (score 6):

As it was already mentioned, your code should work if you have permissions to write for this path. However, it is important that **directory must exist**. If you make call for non-existing folder:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(r"D:\Some new non-existing folder\aaa.db")
```

It will not work, you will have

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file.
```

The same is for relative paths:

```
1) conn = sqlite3.connect(r"aaa.db") 
2) conn = sqlite3.connect(r"Some new folder\aaa.db")
```

First will always work, because you are working in already existing directory and second will not work if you do not create te folder beforehand.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure .connect will create the file if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

```
import sqlite3
conn=sqlite3.connect('xx.db')
print "Database created and opened succesfully"
```

Answer (score 0):

.connect should create a new database file on the fly,  given sub-directories do exist, and you have adequate permissioning.

Comment: While the answer is correct imho it doesn't add any value: It's all been said before